# if get_post_meta is empty do something

Tags: post-meta

I need opposite of this:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_list_category1', true) )  : ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>
```

In other words I want `style="display:none;"` only when meta data doesn't exist.

I thought it would be straightforward like `if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_list_category1', true` but this true/false turns out to be a completely different stuff.

any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<del>You could use the `empty` function inside your `if` as such :</del>

```
<?php if( empty( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_list_category1', true ) ) ) : ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>
```

The above returns an error, you should assign the return value to a variable. See my edit below.

**Warning**

`empty` might not be the best option depending on the values you store in the meta. Values like `false`, `0` etc... will be considered empty.

Check the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for the full list of values that are considered empty.

**Edit**

You can try assigning the meta to a variable, and using that in the `if` statement.

```
 <?php
      $price_list = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_list_category1', true );
 ?>
```

And then...

```
 if( empty( $price_list) ) : ?>style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: You could assign the meta return value to a variable and use that variable inside the `if`. See my edit.

Comment: it appears empty has limitations, and need plain variable to do its magic. one of those php limitations that make no sense.

Comment: Some functions like empty() aren't functions in the normal sense. They're implemented as language features/keywords that evaluate a variable directly instead of passing a value to a function.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `metadata_exists();` (worked for me)for checking for any post meta and the do whatever you want.

```
    // Check and get a post meta

if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, '_meta_key' ) ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_meta_key', true );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this via searching for a solution myself, but it dawned on me the answer is very simple. You simply need to check if the value is empty, if it is then echo nothing - if it has content, then display the content - the code i used is below and can be tailored accordingly to anyone who needs to use it.

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page-sub-title', true );
    if ($meta == '') {
        echo '&nbsp;';
    } else {
        echo '<h2>' . $meta . '</h2>';
      }
?>
```

Comment: works but why `get_the_ID()` instead of good ol `$post->ID`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! in_array( 'given_key', get_post_custom_keys($post_id) ) ) {}
```

Here it is written: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#user-contributed-notes

[get_post_custom_keys](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys) Returns an array containing the keys of all custom fields of a particular post or page. For me, this is the best solution :)