# Using previous_post_link next_post_link but with a filter on a custom field

Tags: php, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have a wordpress site in which I have setup a **custom field** *show_post* of type True / False.

Lets me control showing of posts of course.

But I can't figure out in php when using **previous_post_link** and **next_post_link**, to only showing posts that have the custom field show_post set as true.

Any ideas would be welcome especially if I am missing something simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if get\_post\_meta is empty do something](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56597/if-get-post-meta-is-empty-do-something)

Comment: This is not a possible duplicate of the question you linked to. It has nothing to do with "if get_post_meta is empty do something". Please reread it.

Comment: Custom field is post meta. You just should do the opposite:  if `get_post_meta` is NOT empty do something. Or it's over-elaborated?

Comment: Ok but we want to know if the previous and next post's meta.custom field is empty. Not the current one. Is there anyway to interrogate the next and previous posts meta?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mike. I was looking to do something similar to you so I viewed your question, and I think you might want to try Max Yudin's suggestion. It worked for me. Simply wrap your previous/next post links with an **if** statement like in the answer he linked to. You will end up with something like `<?php $showpostvalue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'show_post', true ); if ( empty( $showpostvalue ) ) : ?> // what you want to show when show_posts is empty <?php else : ?> // what you want to show when the value is true <?php endif; ?>`. Give it a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome jsmod. get_post_meta() only returns data for the current post. I need to examine the data for both the next and previous post before I can decide what to do.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I missed that part of your explanation. Just to clarify your question: are you looking for a way to display the prev/next post links on only the posts with a `show_post` value of `true`, so that no post with a value of `false` will ever show up as a previous/next post on `single.php`? Or is it something else...?

Comment: Yes when I click next/prev, I only want to see posts with a custom field "show_post" with value true. No posts with value of false will ever show up when next/prev clicked. Could I use the $excluded_terms argument in previous_post_link and next_post_link?

Comment: You could use `$excluded_terms` if all the "false" posts were in the same category - since `$excluded_terms` only works with categories. Alternatively, you could put all the "true" posts in the same category and then limit the prev/next post links with `$in_same_term`. But if your true/false posts already share the same category, then none of the above would work and you would instead need that filter you set out to seek :) I wish I could type one up, but I'm still learning about them so my knowledge is very limited. Hopefully, someone more experienced will chip in with a solution soon.

Comment: I found  [This solution ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139453/filter-next-post-link-and-previous-post-link-by-meta-key). Do I call these functions and then previous_post_link?

Comment: hi mike, found your edit. should have commented though, but i guess you don't have enough se reputation. so in [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262451/10994) i run a filter on default wordpress functions. filters let you manipulate the data inside functions, so when you return the manipulated data, the function might return, what you want from it. in my case i have 2 functions, one for mysql join, so i can see the meta related to a post. and the second one checks for the meta. inside these functions i check for the post type (work) you would need to change that to post..